# how to swap index of 2 document in mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, mongoose

How can I swap the position of two documents in mongoose model.
I can also delievier documents _id's if necessary.

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  //my prop
});

mongoose.model('Job', Schema);

swap(index1,index2) 
{
   Job... //swap
}
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327066/swap-the-values-in-a-mongodb-array?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hi, @RohitShukla in the link you've attached, it's a different problem. he want to swap item within a document property "geo". 
I want to swap items within a monogo collection.