# Swap elements in a MongoDB array given only their ids (in-place)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, insert-update

I read some threads about it, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327066/swap-the-values-in-a-mongodb-array) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223273/get-n-th-element-of-an-array-in-mongodb), but they both come with major flaws & caveats (to me at least).

##### What I want is simple! An update query that:

- swaps 2 elements in an array.
- each element is a sub-document.
- I am only given the two indexes as input, of those which need to be swapped.
- I want to AVOID using a javascript function, if at all possible.
- I want it to BE ATOMIC!

Here is the part i'm struggling with:

### Option 1: Using update WITH an aggregation pipeline

( **summary:** succeeds at $arrayElemAt, fails over at "images.0" )

```
db.users.update(
    { userID: 1 },
    [
        { $set: { 
            "images.0": { $arrayElemAt: ['$images', 2] },
            "images.2": { $arrayElemAt: ['$images', 0] },
        }}
    ]
)
```

If I use an aggregation in my update, I get access to the $arrayElemAt operator, which is great! But this solution fails because this → "images.0" doesn't do what I expect it too. I would have expected it to say "hey, please override the first element inside the images array". But no, what it does is it pushes a new field called **"0": { ... }**, to each and every sub-document inside the images array.

### Option 2: Using update WITHOUT an aggregation pipeline

( **summary:** succeeds at "images.0", fails over at $arrayElemAt)

```
db.users.update(
    { userID: 1 },
    { $set: { 
        "images.0": { $arrayElemAt: ['$images', 2] },
        "images.2": { $arrayElemAt: ['$images', 0] },
    }}
)
```

This one fails & succeeds exactly at the opposite places.
The "images.n" DOES replace the n'th element with the given input.
The problem here is, since it is no longer an aggregation, I have no access to the $arrayElemAt operator, and the new n'th element simply becomes:

```
{
    "$arrayElemAt" : [
        "$aboutMe.images",
        2.0
    ]
},
```

Does anyone know what can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice question that I didn't meet before.
The catch here, is that you need a pipeline to refer existing values, but this prevents working with direct index like dot notation or even `$push`.
Hence, one option is using `$reduce`:

1. `$set` keys for the wanted values.
2. `$reduce` with reference to the size of `$$value`, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834345/how-to-add-array-index-field-to-items-in-mongodb-nested-array), in order to replace.

```
db.users.update(
{userID: 1},
[
  {$set: {
      firstItem: {$arrayElemAt: ["$images",  2]},
      secondItem: {$arrayElemAt: ["$images", 0]}
    }
  },
  {$set: {
      images: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$images",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {$cond: [
                  {$eq: [{$size: "$$value"}, 0]},
                  ["$firstItem"],
                  {$cond: [{$eq: [{$size: "$$value"}, 2]}, 
                           ["$secondItem"],
                           ["$$this"]]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      firstItem: "$$REMOVE",
      secondItem: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2d9wk8Qaia8)